# Go Template if condition

Tags: go, devops, go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

how can i combine `and` and `eq/ne` functions together?

I wrote this snippet

```
{{ define "opsgenie.default.tmpl" }}
  <font size="+0"><b>{{.CommonLabels.alertname }}</b></font>
  {{- range $i, $alert := .Alerts }}
  <font size="+0">{{ .Annotations.description }}</font>
  {{- end -}}
  {{- "\n" -}}
  {{- "\n" -}}
  {{- if and eq .CommonLabels.infoalert "true" eq .CommonLabels.topic "database" -}}
  Grafana: https://{{ .CommonLabels.url }}
  {{- "\n" -}}{{- end -}}
  {{- if and ne .CommonLabels.infoalert "true" eq .CommonLabels.topic "database" -}}
  Database:
    • https://{{ .CommonLabels.url }}/
    • https://{{ .CommonLabels.url }}/
  {{- "\n" -}}{{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The goal is:

- if my alert contains both labels `infoalert: true` and `topic: database` then show only Grafana link
- if my alert contains only label `topic: database` but not `infoalert: true` then show only Databsse link

It looks like the syntax for condition `{{- if and eq .CommonLabels.infoalert "true" eq .CommonLabels.topic "database" -}}` is not correct because i get this error in alertmanager.log when alert is fired:

```
notify retry canceled due to unrecoverable error after 1 attempts: templating error: template: email.tmpl:24:17: executing \"opsgenie.default.tmpl\" at <eq>: wrong number of args for eq: want at least 1 got 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use parenthesis to group the expressions:

```
{{- if and (eq .CommonLabels.infoalert "true") (eq .CommonLabels.topic "database") -}}

{{- if and (ne .CommonLabels.infoalert "true") (eq .CommonLabels.topic "database") -}}
```

See this testable example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

    m := map[string]any{
        "infoalert": "true",
        "topic":     "database",
    }
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Second round")
    m["infoalert"] = "false"
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `
{{- if and (eq .infoalert "true") (eq .topic "database") -}}
    infoalert is true and topic is database
{{- end -}}
{{- if and (ne .infoalert "true") (eq .topic "database") -}}
    infoalert is NOT true and topic is database
{{ end }}
`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_AS5mPeaZwJ)):

```
infoalert is true and topic is database
Second round
infoalert is NOT true and topic is database
```